# Storing credentials in cookies?

Tags: cookies, credentials

Is there any use case where you would store hashed credentials in a cookie?

**EDIT**

I was discussing this problem with a colleague if it's advisable to do this. 
Since then, I found an example where a hashed password was used in the cookie.

Why would you even store hashed passwords inside a cookie?

[image: Cookie Settings]

Comment: Define "credentials". Session identifiers could be seen as credentials, in which case the answer is "yeah, pretty much always". If you're talking about passwords, then no, don't do that.

Comment: I assume the asked is referring to username+password as credentials. I don't know of any valid use case for storing a hash of username+password in a cookie.

Comment: not a good idea, imagine a xss attack like `browser.cookies.getAll()`

Comment: Just asking *"is there any use case for ..."* without any kind of context is a bit strange in my opinion. Either you stumbled over some application which behaves this way or some developer suggested this to you to solve a particular problem or you found some example code which does this and wonder where such thing could be used or ... . Please add this kind of missing context to your question.

Comment: I meant usernames and their corresponding passwords. Sorry for the confusion. Sorry for not providing the relevant information - This question came up in an discussion about securely using cookies.

Comment: @HTTP502 In that case [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/202955/151903) may be relevant. There's really no good reason to store passwords or password hashes in cookies, although it's hard to be 100% sure that's what's going on in your screenshot without testing a valid password against the hash. It could just be a poorly named cookie.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald thanks for your information. I changed the password and the hash inside the cookie changed as well. So I hardly asume, that this was the hashed password.